# How can we attach a jquery function to a div that has been appended after the page was loaded, without any event being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can we attach a Jquery function to a div that has been appended after the page was loaded, **without** any event being triggered.

In the example below defaultTab-28 is the div that has been **appended later** to the page.

```
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('defaultTab-28')"
```

and now I want to use **toggle function on the "defaultTab-28" div** like

```
function toggleDiv(divId){
     $("#" + divId).toggle();
}
```

If I use .delegate() or .on() I will have to **specify the event** like click etc, but in this case event trigger is not necessary.

Edit: to be a more precise:

I know using inline JS is not good when using JQuery, I could have used button click function from JQuery, but my question is : Is there any function like .on or .delegate to assign a function without an event

1. I have added a div to an existing page
2. When anybody clicks the  tag I want the div that is passed to the javascript   function which here is my div to use jquery toggle , but because this div is added later it cannot bind to toggle function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already works as is, you don't need to do anything about the div not existing yet.

http://jsfiddle.net/97GZb/

```
function toggleDiv(id){
    $("#" + id).toggle();
}

setTimeout(function(){
    $("body").append("<div id='defaultTab-28'>I'm the div!!!</div>");
},5000);
```

with this html:

```
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('defaultTab-28')">Click me to toggle the div that will be appended in 5 seconds.</a> ​
```

And to answer your comment:

> I know using inline JS is not good when using JQuery, I could have used button click function from JQuery, but my question is : Is there any function like .on or .delegate to assign a function without an event

No, there has to be an event of some kind to tell the javascript engine when to run the code. An element being added to the page is an Event, it is called a Mutation Event. there are also Mutation Observers that can handle this as well that were meant to be a replacement for Mutation Events. Neither of the two have very good cross-browser support.

Comment: Doesn't he want the toggle onClick?

Comment: @HristoYankov I don't know, you tell me. That's how i interpreted his question, and how you appeared to interpret it based on the comment you made on his question.

Comment: @HristoYankov, the OP states, _"...but in this case event trigger is not necessary"_

Comment: I think your code is good +1.  However, I believe the OP erroneously thinks that when he "toggles", he's "appending".

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript

```
function toggleDiv(divObj){
     $(divObj).toggle();
}
```

HTML (the thing you will append later):

```
<div onClick='toggleDiv(this);'></div>
```

Comment: Inline JS on a page using jQuery? Sloppy.

Comment: Oh excuse me for providing a solution while anyone else is misunderstanding his question in the comments.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand the question.

Comment: If you understood it, please post an answer, I will be happy to see it.

Comment: @HristoYankov Your comment on his question regarding what he is looking for doesn't match what your answer suggests to do to fix it.

Comment: @KevinB, actually my solution matches exactly what I said in the comment to his question. My solution and your solution is the same, except that your is kind of wrong, because you fire the toggle on the DIV immediately.

Comment: Nobody understood the question, hence the multiple comments asking the OP to fix it!

Comment: I know using inline JS is not good when using JQuery, I could have used button click function from JQuery, but my question is : Is there any function like .on or .delegate to assign a function without an event

Comment: Jesus F Christ, I give up after @yesIcan last comment here. Good night.

Comment: @yesIcan No. There has to be an event.

Comment: @KevinB thanks for answering the question. Looks like it should have worked as it is, but for some weird reason it is not. But I think you have answered this question. Please answer the same and I will accept it. I dont think there is a way to accept a comment

Comment: @KevinB Also your clarification that we cannot bind a jquery function without event is useful which is what I wanted to clarify